# Sass - undefined error $helvetica

Tags: sass, bourbon, middleman-4

Working with middleman and using Bourbon, Neat and Bitters. Once I start the server, I get following error message -

```
Error compiling CSS asset
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$helvetica"
in (source/stylesheets/base.css.scss: 1)

source/stylesheets/base/_variables.css.scss:1
```

I've looked into open issues and other thoughtbot forums and tried all the resolution steps mentioned there without any success

My `base.css.scss` is as follows -

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import "bourbon";
@import "base/base";
@import "neat";

@import "partials/layout";
@import "partials/nav";
@import "partials/footer";

@import "highlight";
```

`_base.css.scss` -

```
@import "variables";
@import "grid-settings";
@import "buttons";
@import "forms";
@import "lists";
@import "tables";
@import "typography";
```

and `_variables.css.scss`

```
$helvetica: 'Oxygen', $helvetica;

// Typography
$base-font-family: $helvetica;
$heading-font-family: $base-font-family;

// Font Sizes
$base-font-size: 1em;

// Line height
$base-line-height: 1.5;
$heading-line-height: 1.2;
...
```

Comment: I don't see where _variables.css.scss is being imported?  I also don't see where $helvetica is defined in the first place.

Comment: @cimmanon `$helvetica` is defined in `_variables.css.scss`. And its been imported in `_base.css.scss`

Comment: Ok, but _base.css.scss has the line `$helvetica: 'Oxygen', $helvetica;`.  If that's the only place `$helvetica` is defined, how were you expecting this to work?

Comment: @cimmanon `$helvetica` is declared as 1st line of `_variables.css.scss`, which is then referenced in `_base.css.scss`. I've updated my que to reflect new info. This was working in earlier version. Last night I updated middleman to v4 and since then getting this error.

Comment: Are you reading the same code I am?  You have a circular reference.  To me, it looks like you're setting `$helvetica`  to itself, except itself hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: @cimmanon I get what you're saying now. There's some issue with how that 1st line is setup in `_variables.css.scss`. But this is how they got installed. Should I just copy values from Github core files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had the same issue as yourself.

Looks like they got rid of the variable `$helvetica` if you are using the latest version of bitters.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/releases/tag/v1.3.0

You will probably want to set bitters in your `gemfile` to an earlier release (I think 1.2 works just not 1.3) and run these commands in source/stylesheets `bitters remove` then `bitters install` again to get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong line is:

```
$helvetica: 'Oxygen', $helvetica;
```

Why? Because you are setting `$helvetica` with `$helvetica`.

I think what you would do is something like

```
$lato: 'Lato', sans-serif;
```

If you are using a google font for example. I hope it is usefull.